# rails eager loading not working with each on include association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following:

order.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :order_lines, :dependent => :destroy
```

order_line.rb

```
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :status, :class_name => "SettingsOption"
```

orders_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @orders = Order.active_w_property.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id,
        :include => {:order_lines => [:service, :status]})
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
...
<%= render :partial => 'order', :collection => @orders %>
...
```

_order.html.erb

```
...
<% order.order_lines.each do |line| %>
  <% total = total + line.price %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= line.service.option.nil? ?
            t(line.service.name) :
            [t(line.service.name), t(line.service.option)].join(" ") %>
    </td>
    <td><%= t(line.description) %></td>
    <td class="align-right"><%= currencify_price(line.price) %></td>
    <td class="align-center"><%= t(line.status.value) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
...
```

log for index.html.erb

```
  ←[4;36;1mOrder Load (2.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT ""very long query""
  ←[4;35;1mOrderLine Load (1.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT `order_lines`.* FROM `order_lines` WHERE (`order_lines`.order_id IN (10134,1
  ←[4;36;1mOrderLine Columns (5.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `order_lines`←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mService Columns (14.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `services`←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mService Load (3.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`services`.`id` IN (6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,10,5)) ←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mSettingsOption Columns (4.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `settings_options`←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mSettingsOption Load (3.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `settings_options` WHERE (`settings_options`.`id` = 167) ←[0m
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering myimmonatie/orders/index
```

log for _order.html.erb

```
Rendered myimmonatie/orders/_order (8.0ms)
  ←[4;36;1mOrderLine Load (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `order_lines` WHERE (`order_lines`.order_id = 10112) ←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`services`.`id` = 1) ←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `settings_options` WHERE (`settings_options`.`id` = 167) ←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`services`.`id` = 5) ←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `settings_options` WHERE (`settings_options`.`id` = 167) ←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`services`.`id` = 3) ←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `settings_options` WHERE (`settings_options`.`id` = 167) ←[0m
  ←[4;35;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`services`.`id` = 2) ←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `settings_options` WHERE (`settings_options`.`id` = 167) ←[0m
```

For the controller index method all the included tables are loaded as expected. But for each order_line in the partial the order_lines are loaded again, though they were loaded before. Also the services are queried each time (though from cache). How can I let everything just be rendered without new querying?

**UPDATE**: using rails 2.3.11

Comment: The good news is that active record isn't hitting the database each time as the responses are cached